# No matching member function for call to std::unordered_map::insert()

Tags: c++, xcode, stl, unordered-map

I tried to insert a pair of values into `map` that's declared as :

```
unordered_map <unsigned int, std::string> map;
```

and when I insert the combination of 2 `string`s to and an `unsigned int` to `map`:

```
map.insert(std::make_pair(count,str1.append(str2)));
```

and Xcode say there's "no matching member function for call to 'insert'". I looked at the [overload list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair), and I am not sure which one I should use in this case. Can someone please tell me?

---

Update: this problem is caused by unsuccesful typedef. I now changed `map` and defined it as `unordered_map<usigned int, string>`

Comment: You didn't say anything about `objects` and how `objects` is related to `string`.

Comment: did you `#include <unordered_map>` ?

Comment: @jogojapan Oh sorry. `objects` is `typedef`ed as `std::string`

Comment: @sithereal yes and I am `using std::unordered_map`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing you can insert into

```
std::unordered_map <unsigned int, objects> map;
```

is a

```
std::pair<unsigned int, objects>
```

You seem to be inserting

```
std::pair<unsigned int, std::string>
```

which will not work unless a `std::string` is implicitly convertible to `objects`.

If there is a implicit conversion from `std::string` to `objects`, then you might want to consider the simpler and possibly more efficient `emplace` interface:

```
map.emplace(count, str1.append(str2));
```